# Where can I buy a customized window?

Tags: windows

Recently my basement window was installed in the wrong orientation (vertical window positioned horizontally), a horizontal window (40x33) is needed, and Home Depot didn't have one. Your advice about where is the best to go for and what feature should be known is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not see them "Online" at HD,  You go to HD, Lowes, etc. and they have several brands to custom order, I selected "Milgard" white, You will provide all the information, rough opening, single, double, triple pane, type of glass (safety film-tempered), gas for insertion, for replacement, new contructions,  finish inside, outside.  Brands may vary depending on locations, as you do not want to be shipping across country. It was delivery to the local HD store, so no shipping charge.  I was surprised by how low the price was.  Plus you can get 20% off by opening a credit card.  I did not know I was custom ordering, just selecting options.  Ask why it took two-three  weeks for delivery and was told it was custom built to my selection criterial. LOL

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to contact a local custom window manufacturer/installer. They'll take a look at your situation and be able to give you a quote for a custom sized window with installation. You'll be able to specify if and how it opens, as well as the frame material, interior & exterior colors, and glass options. Note that a good salesman will be reasonably familiar with basement egress code requirements for your area and will honestly admit that he'll have to look them up if he's not 100% certain on your exact local codes. (i.e. whether this window will *have* to open or if it can be a fixed unit.)

I'd actually suggest calling 2 or 3 (or more, if you have the time and patience) to have them come out and give you quotes. They'll each go through their sales pitch, too, and a bad salesman may even try to get you to replace more windows than just the one you're having issues with. A good tip is that's the guy you do *NOT* want to buy from.

Alternatively, many large US big-box home improvement stores will also be able to order custom windows for you. You may not have as many options, and will either have to do the install yourself or pay extra to have them install it for you, and the price may not be significantly lower than a custom window from a local installer. Be sure to consider that when making your price comparisons.